# Is there any way to groupby a df in pandas and then add a column of values from the regression model to the df all at once?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to use the same in Python.
Is there any way to groupby a df in pandas and then add a column of values from the regression model to the df all at once?
What is the smartest way?

```
# This is R. Very smart and useful.
library(tidyverse)
iris_lm <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% 
  do(lm.res = lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length, data = .)) %>%
  mutate(coe = lm.res$coefficients[2])
iris_lm
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Rowwise: 
  Species    lm.res   coe
  <fct>      <list> <dbl>
1 setosa     <lm>   0.132
2 versicolor <lm>   0.686
3 virginica  <lm>   0.750
```

Comment: There are several packages to mimic `R` syntax in python like [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) for data manupulation.

Comment: Hi Michael Szczesny,  thanks for sharing a very nice package!
It's very easy to understand for R users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this similary with [`statsmodels`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.formula.api.ols.html) using the most common pattern in `pandas`: [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)[`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Setting up the dataset from `sklearn`

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm

iris = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=['sepal_length','sepal_width','petal_length','petal_width'])
```

Using the `sm.ols` api

```
(df.assign(species = iris.target_names[iris.target])
   .groupby('species')
   .apply(lambda x: sm.ols('petal_length ~ sepal_length', x).fit().params[1])
   .reset_index(name='coe'))
```

Output

```
      species       coe
0      setosa  0.131632
1  versicolor  0.686470
2   virginica  0.750081
```

Comment: Hi Michael Szczesny, Thank you for teaching me how to write the Python way in a very clear way.
I'm an R person, but I've been thinking that I should learn how to write in Python style, so I learned a lot.